# Why is there no kbd button in the text editor?

Tags: feature-request

There should be a kbd button in the text editor, so users don't have to manually write `<kbd>CTRL</kbd>` ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd> ) all the time.

There would be much more people using it. I almost never use these tags because most of the times I am to lazy for it or have no time, the button would help a lot!

> Kevin B. said "can see people abusing it for things that aren't keyboard buttons."

In this case the Stack Overflow developers should program it so that it only renders anything which is allowed. E.g. if someone writes <kbd>foo</kbd> then it should just not get rendered.

If the user submits then the whole text should be checked for any unallowed inputs server side, if there are some unallowed inputs then remove them and send the new text back to the client without posting it.

I also suggest virtual keyboards, where users are limited to the inputs of that keyboard, at this way they could also post a windows symbol.

Comment: i dunno if more people using it would be a good thing

Comment: @KevinB Why do you think that keyboard buttons are a bad idea?

Comment: @ProEvilz true story, I never had one single upvote in meta afaik, only downvotes.

Comment: @ProEvilz [Voting is different on meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). _**On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement** with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself._

Comment: I don't think keyboard buttons are a bad idea. I just don't see them being useful in the majority of posts, and can see people abusing it for things that aren't keyboard buttons.

Comment: @FirstOne Yes they are... hover over a downvote button for the tooltip and you will see. - `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`

Comment: @ProEvilz I'm not respoding to this. Check my edited comment. I'm not the one saying it! Edit: _"Yes they are"_ is to my original comment _"votes are not the same in meta"_

Comment: @ProEvilz It's absolutely usual, especially with [tag:feature-request]s,

Comment: @KevinB, then they could make a virtual keyboard instead, and if you press a key, then you should get the key as output.

Comment: ... wat... i don't even...

Comment: @KevinB, you don't even?

Comment: The point @KevinB is trying to make, is that the amount of work necessary to build such a feature is way too much compared to the benefit it could provide.

Comment: @Stijn, im not sure how you came to this conclusion from his "i don't even' answer. My english is maybe not the best.

Comment: yeah, my expression was more of a *i don't understand what you are suggesting*

Comment: Checking serverside would only work on submit, it would make the preview and end result differ. What keyboard formats need to be supported? phone virtual keyboards too? they have emoji buttons. All this for a feature that rarely even has a use here.

Comment: I suggested a virtual keyboard, where users are limited to the inputs of that keyboard. But this is a bad idea, since they can still edit the output.

Comment: The preview and end result would differ, yes. But would this really mather in this case?

Comment: People are already abusing `code formatting` way too much, I'm not sure I want them to abuse `<kbd>` too. About your suggestion for not rendering anything that doesn't have anything to do with the keyboard, I'm not sure that will work out because as far as I know, there is no unicode character for the Windows logo, so for the Windows key, you would have to do something like `<kbd>![](example.com/windowslogo.png)</kbd>` (you could always write `<kbd>Windows</kbd>`, but an image looks a lot nicer). And there is no way to check automatically if the image is a Windows logo or something unallowed.

Comment: Wait, i revert my last comment. The preview and end result would NOT differ, since the user would get informed about it before the post is finally getting posted, so he always has the chance to preview the current text.

Comment: @DonaldDuck, the windows symbol problem would be solved with the virtual keyboard which I have talked about.

Comment: [Edit Overflow](http://pmortensen.eu/) can do just that (Ctrl + B (on the clipboard content)).

Comment: So much hate and oppression in this thread. People manage to ask millions of awful questions abusing the 24 letters of the alphabet, ever thought about that huh????????

Answer (score 17):

[This is pretty much why we don't advertise that too much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974/50049), and why we can't have nice things for the most part.

Just keep scrolling. If you find a sudden urge to build your own castle, there's [always the sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Comment: Then it should be scripted so that it does only render allowed inputs, and everything else should not be rendered. Problem solved.

Comment: If the user submits then the whole text should be checked for any unallowed inputs server side, if there are some unallowed inputs then remove them and send the new text back to the client, with a message informing him what he did wrong.

Comment: @Black I see very few posts where using the `<kbd>` would make a question more clear and easier to read.  Most programming problems don't involve indicating which keys you are pressing.  On other sites (like Super User, or any of the LINUX sites) it might make more sense, but not on SO.  Is there a practical use case I'm not thinking of?

Comment: @psubsee2003 mostly editor related things. Search "ctrl" on SO for some examples, there's 80k plus of them

Comment: @psubsee2003 [tag:vim] tag might be an exception, but `<kbd>` is very useful there (and obviously vi.SE), given that most answers would look like gibberish to newbies.

Answer (score 17):

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>Because.</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Comment: I already solved this problem theoretically. Read my comments and question again... It wouldn't be hard to solve this problem.

Comment: Indeed, but consider the following equation (0 problems (by not allowing it in the first place)) > (1 problem (by allowing it) - 1 solution (by building a feature making it less of a problem))

Comment: That said, `<kbd>` is totally rad and we should be able to use it everywhere, including in titles. Never going to happen though.

Comment: @Pekka웃, so in other words, the devs have not the capacity to develope this or are simply too lazy

Comment: @Black probably neither - but they have a *lot* more important things on their plate. Things with a lot more practical importance and relevance.

Comment: On mobile, this looks like a Mayan pyramid with a very strange sacrifice altar on top. Can't unsee.